# Examples of specific points $g\in G:=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ such that the curve $u_tg \Gamma, \Gamma:=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ is dense in $G/\Gamma$?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $G:=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$, $\Gamma:=\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ and $u_t=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & t \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}, t\ge 0$

Although this paragraph is not really needed to answer this question, I want to point out that ergodic theory tells us that **for almost every** point $g\Gamma$ in $G/\Gamma$ (with respect to Haar measure), we have $\{u_tg\Gamma\}_{t\ge 0}$ is dense in $G/\Gamma$ (Howe-Moore theorem tells us $u_t$ acts ergodically on $G/\Gamma$)

But how to produce **any specific** $g$'s such that $\{u_tg\Gamma\}_{t\ge 0}$ is dense in $G/\Gamma$? I guess there are some Diophantine approximation theorem that I am not familiar with. Perhaps we need $g$'s entries to be linearly independent over rationals.

Comment: Are you familiar with Ratner's theorems?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Does Ratner's theorem help me produce any specific $g$'s? If so I am happy to know! Ratner theorems' statements are not too hard to learn.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz emmm... this seems to be related to Ratner's distribution rigid theorem as in her 1991 Duke Paper page 236.

Comment: I'm curious what kind of answer you are expecting. Like all real numbers, the entries of the matrix $g$ can be described by some kind of approximation scheme, which may or may not be "Diophantine approximation".

Answer (score 2):

If you want a specific matrix $g$, you can take
$$
g=\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
\sqrt{2}&1\end{array}\right].
$$
Here is the reason. Let $U_\infty$ denote the subgroup of strictly upper triangular matrices in $G$. Then for $g\in G$,
$$
U_\infty g = g U, \quad U=g^{-1}U_\infty g. 
$$
The unique fixed-point of $U$ in the ideal boundary of the hyperbolic plane is $g^{-1}(\infty)=\frac{a}{c}$, where
$$
g^{-1}=\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
c&d\end{array}\right].
$$
Thus, $U\cap \Gamma$ is a lattice in $U$ if and only if $g^{-1}(\infty)\in {\mathbb Q}\cup\{\infty\}$. In particular, for my choice of $g$ as above, $g^{-1}(\infty)= -1/\sqrt{2}\notin {\mathbb Q}$, hence,   $U\cap \Gamma$ is not a lattice in $U$. Ratner proves (see [here](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Echaika/Ratner_SL2) for a free copy of her paper) in

*Ratner, Marina*, [**Raghunathan’s conjectures for SL(2,R)**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02808152), Isr. J. Math. 80, No. 1-2, 1-31 (1992). [ZBL0785.22013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0785.22013).

that for a nontrivial unipotent subgroup $U< G$ a coset $U\Gamma$ is either dense in $G/\Gamma$ or $U\cap \Gamma$ is a lattice in $U$. But, in fact, if you look at her proof closer, she proves density not only for the entire $U$-coset but also for cosets of connected semigroups in $U$. Thus, for $g$ as above, the $u_t$-semigroup orbit of $g\Gamma$ is dense in $G$.